# Trying to add table captions to tables using pseudo elements

Tags: css

I understand why my code doesn't work, it is because the tables have separate parents. The problem is, I cannot think of a way to get it to work using CSS. The HTML is generated by a text editor similar to TinyMCE, so it is not really an option to change the HTML structure.

What I'm asking, is there a way to make this work without javascript? I want to have Table - 1, Table -2, Table - 3, and so on, as table pseudo elements. Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<div class="post-body">
  <div>random div with content</div>
  <div>
    <div class="table-box">
      <table border="1" bordercolor="#888" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>yellow</td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>blue</td>
            <td>green</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>random div with content</div>
  <div>random div with content</div>
  <div>
    <div class="table-box">
      <table border="1" bordercolor="#888" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>yellow</td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>blue</td>
            <td>green</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>random div with content</div>
  <div>random div with content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.post-body .table-box {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.post-body div .table-box table:before {
  content: "TABLE";
  display: table-caption;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}

.post-body div .table-box:nth-of-type(1) table:before {
  content: "TABLE - 1";
}

.post-body div .table-box:nth-of-type(2) table:before {
  content: "TABLE - 2";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible with CSS counters. See example and for more information the provided link.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp

```css
/* I used "table" as the counters name, feel free to use your own naming system. */

.post-body {
 counter-reset: table; /* Set counter reset, every counter within this class will be one "group" */
}
 .table-box {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  counter-increment: table; /* every element with this will increase the counter */
}

.post-body div .table-box table:before {
  content: "TABLE - " counter(table); /* display the count */
  display: table-caption;
  margin: 0 0 0.25rem 0;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  line-height: 1;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<div class="post-body">
  <div>random div with content</div>
  <div>
    <div class="table-box">
      <table border="1" bordercolor="#888" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>yellow</td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>blue</td>
            <td>green</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>random div with content</div>
  <div>random div with content</div>
  <div>
    <div class="table-box">
      <table border="1" bordercolor="#888" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>yellow</td>
            <td>red</td>
            <td>blue</td>
            <td>green</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>random div with content</div>
  <div>random div with content</div>
</div>
```